# Keeping band names when exporting a GeoTIFF from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to export an image as a GeoTIFF through Google Earth Engine but I can't seem to find a way to retain the band names. They look like this before exporting.

[image: How the band names look like before exporting]

When I open the GeoTIFF after exporting, however, the band names are just `['b1, 'b2', 'b3']`.

[image: How Bands are renamed after].

This is my code for exporting the image (building_info). Has anyone found a way to retain the band names when exporting an image to a GeoTIFF?

```
Export.image.toDrive({
 image: building_info,
 description: 'test',
 folder: 'sentinel_buildings',
 region: bbox,
 scale: 10
})
```

Comment: How do you read in the GeoTiff to check the names after the export?

Comment: @JonasV my workflow consists of exporting Sentinel 2 data from Google Earth Engine as a GeoTiff. To see the GeoTiff's names after the export, I import the GeoTiff in Google Earth Engine as an Asset. All the data is the same except the band name.

Comment: @rgb_123, did you figure out a way to preserve bandnames? Having the same issue.

Comment: @jblng sadly no. I have found that if you set the format options to

`formatOptions = {
                                                           'cloudOptimized' :  True
                                                       })`

when exporting the image in the Export.image.toCloudStorage() the band Names will be readable in certain programs. I believe it was with the R package 'Raster' you can get the band names but it's been a while since I've tried.

Comment: @rgb_123 thanks for the reply. I will give this a go, was hoping to read in bandnames using ArcGIS Pro. Will otherwise try with python.